# Where did the javax.xml.registry.infomodel package from Jakarta EE 8 disappear to in Jakarta EE 9.1?

Tags: jakarta-ee, java-package, jakarta-ee-9

I would specifically like to use the [TelephoneNumber](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/8/apidocs/javax/xml/registry/infomodel/telephonenumber) class which I found in the [javax.xml.registry.infomodel package in the Jakarta EE 8 javadoc](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/8/apidocs/javax/xml/registry/infomodel/package-summary.html).

Looking in the [Jakarta EE 9.1 javadocs](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/9.1/apidocs/), I can't find an equivalent package or TelephoneNumber class. I can't find any notes about its removal in the list of deprecations in either version.